# How to filter out all params of a POST request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging

I am making the following POST request to `some_action` in the `ApiController`:

```
HTTParty.post( 'https://example.com/api/some_action.json?token=foo',
               headers: {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'},
               body: {some_key: 'some_value'}.to_json
             )
```

I am trying to filter out the content of the submitted body, because it contains sensitive information. However, my log writes:

```
Started POST "/api/some_action.json?token=[FILTERED]" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-11-28 12:30:32 +0100
Processing by ApiController#some_action as JSON
  Parameters: {"some_key"=>"[FILTERED]", "token"=>"[FILTERED]", "api"=>{"some_key"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
```

When I expect the params I get the params I get:

```
def some_action
  Rails.logger.error params
  # => {"some_key"=>"some_value", "token"=>"foo", "controller"=>"api", "action"=>"some_action", "format"=>"json", "api"=>{"some_key"=>"some_value"}}
end
```

It seems that there is an extra param called `api`, which I suppose refers to the controller name. But I can't filter it. I can filter some_key param, but not the entire `api` param. Any idea how I can filter the `api` and how I can avoid to have the params written twice in the log? I have tried the following without success:

```
config.filter_parameters += [:api, :some_key]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lib/params_filter.rb`

```
class ParamsFilter
  def self.filter(params)
    params.except(:api, :some_key)
  end
end
```

and then in your code:

```
rails.logger.error ParamsFilter.filter(params)
```